# Keras model predicts different results using the same input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction

I built a Keras sequential model on the simple dataset. I am able to train the model, however every time I try to get a prediction on the same input I get different values. Anyone knows why? I read through different Stackoverflow here ([Why the exactly identical keras model predict different results for the same input data in the same env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321976/why-the-exactly-identical-keras-model-predict-different-results-for-the-same-inp), [Keras saved model predicting different values on different session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624965/keras-saved-model-predicting-different-values-on-different-session), [different prediction after load a model in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744552/different-prediction-after-load-a-model-in-keras)), but couldn't find the answer. I tried to set the Tensorflow seed and still getting different results.
Here is my code

```
from pandas import concat
from pandas import DataFrame
# create sequence
length = 10
sequence = [i/float(length) for i in range(length)]
# create X/y pairs
df = DataFrame(sequence)
df = concat([df, df.shift(1)], axis=1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df)
# convert to LSTM friendly format
values = df.values
X, y = values[:, 0], values[:, 1]
X = X.reshape(len(X), 1, 1)
print(X.shape, y.shape)
```

output is:

```
     0    0
1  0.1  0.0
2  0.2  0.1
3  0.3  0.2
4  0.4  0.3
5  0.5  0.4
6  0.6  0.5
7  0.7  0.6
8  0.8  0.7
9  0.9  0.8
(9, 1, 1) (9,)
```

Then start building the model

```
#configure network
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
tf.random.set_seed(1337)

n_batch = len(X)
n_neurons = 10
#design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(n_batch, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X,y,epochs=2,batch_size=n_batch,verbose=1,shuffle=False)
```

Now every time I run the following code to get the prediction I get different results as you can see here

```
model.predict(X)
********output**************
 array([[0.03817442],
       [0.07164046],
       [0.10493257],
       [0.13797525],
       [0.17069395],
       [0.20301574],
       [0.23486984],
       [0.26618803],
       [0.29690543]], dtype=float32)
```

```
model.predict(X)
********output**************
array([[0.04415776],
       [0.08242793],
       [0.12048437],
       [0.15823033],
       [0.19556962],
       [0.2324073 ],
       [0.26865062],
       [0.3042098 ],
       [0.33899906]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Do you know what stateful set to True does in a LSTM?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it setting stateful to True will save the last state for each sample and use it as initial state for next sample. But I thought that is for building the model only, am I wrong? here is the explanation by Tensorflow docs. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM

Comment: correct, but it is not only for training, also for prediction

Comment: Thank you so much, you are correct. I turned that to False and started working. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is setting `stateful=True` in your LSTM layer, as this keeps the state between predict calls, so each prediction depends on previous predictions.

So as a solution, set `stateful=False`.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-determinism/) library and the documentation attached to it will be interesting for your work.

Based on the above library, in a recent work I had with the Keras, I was starting the code as follows:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import seed
seed(42)
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
import tensorflow
tensorflow.random.set_seed(42)
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
```

There seemed to be a good deal of determinism in the results, and it was good enough for what I was working on at the time.

**UPDATE**: The linked library is now deprecated. Besides that, now [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/reproducibility_recipes/) has its own recipe to deal with determinism.

Comment: No, this is just an incorrect guess.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Is it possible that these models can behave deterministically? If yes, how to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Dr.Snoopy the problem was setting stateful = True. Setting it to False fixed the issue. "Boolean (default False). If True, the last state for each sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the sample of index i in the following batch." and my misunderstanding was that this only applies to training.

Thanks to @Dr.Snoopy for pointing that out.